# After importing Normalize.css file in my stylesheet , My webpage has a Horizontal scrollbar and white space on right side

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, normalize-css

I created an SCSS file. Then copy-pasted all CSS styles of Normalize.css. Then I imported that file in style.SCSS. After that my webpage shows a horizontal scrollbar and white space on the right side. I can't find which portion of the code is responsible for this.
I am giving you all the Normalize.css code which I imported. [Gist link](https://gist.github.com/shahab570/e6d50db9e698dc99dc457209275bfde6)

Answer (score 1):

probably because of the overflow visible. Change that to overflow: hidden; or manage the width of your components. or if there is text expanding the with add something like: word-wrap: break-word;
its hard to say without seeing the actual bug
check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow fot mor info on overflow.